# dmidecode and DDR3 memory

Tags: linux, memory, fedora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect memory type under Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/265565/how-to-detect-memory-type-under-linux)

I got NC9C-550-LF motherboard with 2 GiB DDR3 1033 MHz memory. but when I look at

```
dmidecode
```

the memory module is shown as below

```
 Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK0
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MHz
    Manufacturer: Manufacturer00
    Serial Number: SerNum00
    Asset Tag: AssetTagNum0
    Part Number: ModulePartNumber00
    Rank: Unknown
```

also, lshw -c memory shows as below

```
*-bank:0
      description: SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
      product: ModulePartNumber00
      vendor: Manufacturer00
      physical id: 0
      serial: SerNum00
      slot: DIMM0
      size: 2GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
```

Are there any other command line tools to identify the memory correctly in Fedora ?